# CMake error with googletest

Tags: c++, cmake

This is my project structure :

```
project rts
│   README.md
│   CMakeLists.txt    
│
└───modules
│   │   CMakeLists.txt
│   │
│   └───utils
│       │   CMakeLists.txt
│       │     
│       └───test
│           │   test_main.cpp
│           └───
```

I have the following error :

```
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "RTSModules" ...) includes target "rts_utils" 
which requires target "gtest_main" that is not in the export set.
```

This comes from me telling CMake that my module rts_utils ($path_to_project/modules/utils/CMakeLists.txt) needs googletest :

```
rts_define_module(utils)
target_link_libraries(rts_utils gtest_main)
```

I'm using the same macros used in OpenCV project, they just start with "rts_" instead of "ocv_".

The problem here is that normally, if googletest was "under my full control", I would add something like that to the CMakeLists.txt of googletest :

```
rts_install_target(gtest gtest_main EXPORT RTSModules ARCHIVE DESTINATION 
${RTS_3P_LIB_INSTALL_PATH} COMPONENT dev)
```

instead of

```
install(TARGETS gtest gtest_main DESTINATION lib)
```

Or at least that's how I see the thing. But my problem is that I followed the steps provided in the googletest README to : "Use CMake to download GoogleTest as part of the build's configure step. This is just a little more complex, but doesn't have the limitations of the other methods."

In other words, I can't modify the CMakeLists.txt of googletest, because I assume anyone using my project will get it on-the-fly. The idea of git submodule would cause similar problems I think.

Do I have to go back to including a "static snapshot" of googletest and modify it with the appropriate EXPORT or **does it exist some magic trick that I don't know ? (I'm no expert of CMake).**

Otherwise than that error message, the test file that uses googletest ($path_to_project/modules/utils/test/test_main.cpp) compiles just fine and runs fine (with CMake).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the utils module CMakeLists.txt, I changed :

```
rts_define_module(utils)
target_link_libraries(rts_utils gtest_main)
```

to :

```
rts_define_module(utils)
```

Instead of linking here, I moved it to the macro that is used to generate tests targets rts(ocv)_add_accuracy_tests() :

```
rts_target_link_libraries(${the_target} ${test_deps} 
      ${RTS_MODULE_${the_module}_DEPS} ${RTS_LINKER_LIBS} gtest_main)
```

This will probably need a check for googletest existence, but for now it will do.